# Is there a way to position n number of divs inside a div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to position n number of divs inside a div container, so that each div cell won't collide each other using css and js.
We need to set the left value without changing the height and top values. It is fine to change the cell width.

Please check this code sample.

```css
.container
 {
   width : 400px;
   height : 1000px;
   background : #000;
   position : relative;
 }

 .cell
 {
   position  :absolute;
   background : yellow;
   border: 2px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="cell" style="top:50px;width:100%;height:100px"></div>  
   <div class="cell" style="top:150px;width:50%;height:50px"></div>
   <div class="cell" style="top:150px;width:50%;height:50px;"></div>
   <div class="cell" style="top:230px;width:33.33%;height:50px;"></div>
   <div class="cell" style="top:230px;width:33.33%;height:50px;"></div>
   <div class="cell" style="top:230px;width:33.33%;height:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: What output are you expecting ?

Comment: Is `position:absolute` necessary?

Comment: Provide at least the output you expect so that we may be able to visualize it better

Comment: Yes. But the top and height values should not change. Also, the cells should not fall outside the container.

Comment: Using position:absolute will make this a pain. Especially if you are wanting this to be done dynamically without code for each different variation of this for different number of divs inside your container. This is a simple fix if the positions do not need to be absolute...gonna need some js and some math to do absolute positioning....also...not really sure what output you are wanting...

Comment: I have added the expected output. Please check.

Comment: I have to goto work, dont have time to finish, but here it is, 90% done, im sure you can take it from here :)    https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJgOYb

Answer (score 0):

If all the cells should be stacked one above the other in the order of their mention, then simply make their display property 'block'

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.cell {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell" style="width:100%;height:100px;"></div>
  <div class="cell" style="width:50%;height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="cell" style="width:50%;height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="cell" style="width:33.33%;height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="cell" style="width:33.33%;height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="cell" style="width:33.33%;height:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the top value of the cells should not be changed.

Comment: @ArunDNambissan are you generating these cells from an array of values, in that case relative-top value can be computed and assigned dynamically.

Comment: Yes. the div is generated using js code. I am able to set the cell top value. What I need is to set the left value.

Comment: can also just use <code>margin-top:00px</code> instead of nasty absolute positioning.

Comment: @ArunDNambissan it will not ensure that there is no overlap

Comment: padding should take care of that :)

Comment: @gurvinder372 can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @ArunDNambissan can you share the complete context? In terms of why do you need to do it at first place?

Answer (score -1):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryEaQr

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="cell"></div>  
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
</div>

.container
    {
      width : 400px;
      height : 1000px;
      background : #000;
      display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    }

    .cell
    {
      flex:1;
      background : yellow;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
```

Using flexbox each row will not colide no matter the size of the container, and with `flex:1;` each row will take as much space as it can. If you were to have `flex-direction:row;` instead each row would take a 6th of the space available.

Answer (score -1):

Use `

> Z-index

` property of CSS.